# Microsoft's X-Tag vs Mozilla's X-Tags

Tags: web-component, custom-element, x-tag

Recently, **Microsoft** started with a new [X-Tag](http://x-tag.github.io/) library to create custom elements. The website says,

> X-Tag is a Microsoft supported, open source, JavaScript library that wraps the W3C standard Web Components family of APIs to provide a compact, feature-rich interface for rapid component development. While X-Tag offers feature hooks for all Web Component APIs (Custom Elements, Shadow DOM, Templates, and HTML Imports), it only requires Custom Element support to operate. In the absence of native Custom Element support, X-Tag uses a set of polyfills shared with Google's Polymer framework. You can view our package options in the Builds section

As far as I remember, not so long ago, even **Mozilla** had a similar project with the exact same name [X-Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Apps/Tools_and_frameworks/Web_components).

How are these projects different from each other? Or are they the same project with a renewed branding?

Comment: Mozilla's is called Mozilla Brick and uses X-Tag.  And as the link from Mozilla going to http://x-tags.org/ redirects too http://x-tag.github.io/ , yes, both X-Tag's are the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging, I managed to find out a [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3t76r1/1st_microsoftsupported_xtag_release_15_just/) which confirms, that they are indeed the same project.

Infact, the original developer - [Daniel](https://twitter.com/csuwildcat) used to work at Mozilla, when he created the X-Tag project but since then he has moved to Microsoft.

Hence, it is now a Microsoft-supported project founded by an x-Mozillian. Also confirmed on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/csuwildcat/status/666692606311555072?s=09).